# Assigning an internet image as a button background?

Tags: android, image, gridview, button

I have a gridview populated with buttons and I would like to set the buttons to be images pulled from the internet.

It appears I can only assign a resid, color, or drawable as the background for the button. Is there some way I can convert an image link to a resid? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

The image links are currently being pulled from an online .txt file, converted into an array and the gridview is populated based on the links.

I have a feeling there isn't going to be an easy answer for this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Download (and optionally cache) the image, convert into some form of drawable, and use that? (Disclaimer: I don't own or emulate smartphones.)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely doable, but you would have to first download the images (in a `Thread`, via an `AsyncTask`, you don't want to keep the main thread hanging while you download your button's images). This would get you `Bitmap`s, then you assign those to your button's background like so: `button.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(theBitmap))`, or something like that.